# Call function in an array in a property of a class

Tags: php, arrays, class, properties

Can someone please explain me why the following doesn't work, or give me a link which explains why? I can't find it here or on google.

**This works:**

```
var_dump( array( 'test' => rand(1,5) ) );
```

**This does not:**

```
$myClass = new myClass();
var_dump($myClass->array);

class myClass {

    public $array = array( 'test' => rand(1,5) );

}
```

It doesn't like the function call in the array:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'
```

I guess it is my lack of understanding. If someone could help me to understand it, this would be nice.

Thanks!

Comment: It does not look me a duplicate one.

Comment: u can`t write it in a class properties

Comment: @ShaktiSingh OP is asking to initialize a property with a computed value, e.g. depends on runtime information. That's the same problem as in the linked duplicate. And it doesnt work for the same reason that's cited in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$myClass = new myClass();
var_dump($myClass->array);

class myClass {

    public $array;

    function myClass(){
        $this -> array =  array( 'test' => rand(1,5) );
    }

}
```

For more details: [What is the better approach to initialize class variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322123/what-is-the-better-approach-to-initialize-class-variables)

Comment: any particular reason why you are using the legacy constructor in your example?

Comment: no particular reason, it just works :)

Comment: … until you put the class into a namespace

Comment: Thanks dev for the link. I already use your way (using the __construct) but was just wondering why it isn't possible to declare it as a property :)